# Cannot integrate Zeplin into Figma project

Tags: android, figma

I would like to integrate Figma with Zeplin. Because I could not connect Figma project with Android Studio which I can do with Zeplin.

I have installed Zeplin and Figma desktop apps on Mac OS Mojave.

I tried to integrate Zeplin with Figma according to this [instruction](https://help.figma.com/article/92-figma-and-zeplin).

But Zeplin button is not clickable:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think this is a tech support question, and generally these are off-topic here because answering them would require access to your system or setup.  Can't you contact the software developers for tech support?

Comment: I found out that it depends on the project file size. If it is big, the project cannot be exported to Zeplin. Here is more details: https://spectrum.chat/figma/help/cannot-export-to-zeplin~4d3e8afa-8196-40a2-b326-3387c3e9c97b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your are viewing the file with only [viewer permissions](https://help.figma.com/article/301-understanding-sharing-permissions). In order to activate Zeplin integration, you have to have access to **edit** the file.

Contact the file owner so they could upgrade you to editor (it require payment if they are on a [Professional team](https://help.figma.com/article/209-figma-plans#professional)). Alternatively you can [make a duplicate](https://help.figma.com/article/379-duplicate-file) of the file to your Drafts folder if you have [permission](https://help.figma.com/article/386-prevent-viewers) to do that.

[image: How to duplicate a file to your Drafts]